# C++ - deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ in 3rd-party header

Tags: c++

I am including a couple of 3rd-party headers into my .cpp file (wrapped in `extern "C"` of course), and I'm getting the annoying `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warning during compilation, even when I don't call the functions defined in the header files. Given that I cannot change the headers, is there a good way to silence/ignore these warnings or do I just have to live with them?

Comment: It depends on your compiler. Most have a pragma/option to disable specific warnings.

Comment: @Loki: C has string literals, which clearly are what we're discussing.  `std::string` doesn't have a conversion to `char*`, deprecated or otherwise, even if constant.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on your compiler. Here's what you'd do for g++:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
#include <files that generate the warning>
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wwrite-strings"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the warning by compiling with `-Wno-write-strings`.

I'm assuming this is `g++` we're talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

your compiler (GCC?) may support disabling warnings over a range of lines or sources.

of course, you should also report the bug to the vendor.

So you'd write something along these lines -- compiler specific:

```
#pragma PUSH COMPILER IGNORE SOME WARNING
#include <third_party_headers.h>
#pragma POP COMPILER IGNORE SOME WARNING
```